# prototype javascript calendar with customizable rendering of cells like YUI Calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, prototypejs

I already make extensive use of prototype and don't want to add an extra framework like YUI.

I need a javascript calendar which enables me to customize rendering of calendar-cells on a cell by cell basis. (For rendering events, prices, etc. on a certain date) .

YUI Calendar makes this possible, but I already make extensive use of prototype and don't want to add an extra framework like YUI.

Does anyone know a good alternative?

Thanks, 
Brits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one: [CalendarView](http://calendarview.org/) and another [CalendarDateSelect](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of upgrading from *Prototype* to **YUI** or **jQuery**?  Both would give you a lot more functionality than prototype and both have excellent calendar options.

Comment: yeah I like JQuery, but Im using tapestry 5 as framework which uses prototype extensively.

Comment: why is YUI or jQuery an upgrade from Prototype?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the time, you can [build your own](http://jszen.blogspot.com/2007/03/how-to-build-simple-calendar-with.html).  I've personally used this blog entry to create my own and it works beautifully.  The code doesn't use Prototype, but as I was walking through it I converted the whole thing into a Prototype class and used all the nice features of Prototype to make the code look better.  And best of all, you know exactly what the tag classes are so **you can customize it completely** (personally it is easier for me to code the CSS as I go rather than trying to reverse engineer a pre-built one, besides, the equivalent jQuery one may be too much or too little for what you want).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [jscalendar](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/) before, which works well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Prototype is a collection of helper functions, but it has no widgets. 
YUI is a total different beast (there's a minor overlapping in DOM methods).
We use Prototype for Ajax calls and YUI for widgets (calendar, dialogs, grid).